# Best way to handle descrete sets of information SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, flask

I'm very new to SQL and am trying to structure a list of objects in a hierarchy. I have a Flask server that accepts information from a client device and stores the information in a MySQL server. Because the Flask server can accept connections from multiple client devices, I want to organize the information from each individual client in the SQL server. My naive approach would be to create a new table for each Client that connects and insert the data into that new table. It's my understanding that this may be the incorrect way to handle the organization of data. My question is what is the standard way of handling this in SQL?

Comment: How refreshing to have someone ask this BEFORE they are neck deep in their bad design decisions. Going your "naive" route will cause you more pain then you can imagine. In a database we want to avoid creating new objects (databases, tables, views, procedures, columns, functions, etc) at all costs. These objects should never contain information at the object level that is necessary for an application to function (I should never query database metadata to see if there is a table customer_xyz_2020 and then make a decision based on that query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and creating a new *table* for each new set of client information is bad practice.  Instead, consider just having a single table, with a separate *column* to keep track of the client, e.g.

```
client_table (client_id, data1, data2, data3, ...)
```

Now, for each new incoming set of client information, you need only to insert a new record for that client.